# Reference for the sobolev space $H^{1/2}([0,1];\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I need a reference for the Sobolev space $H^{1/2}([0,1]; \mathbb{R}^{n})$. The article that I am reading says that this space consists of all $L^2$ curves $\gamma: [0,1] → R^n$ such that the coefficients $(x_k)_{k\in Z}$ of the Fourier decomposition 
\begin{equation}
\gamma (t) = \displaystyle\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-2\pi kJt}x_k,\;\; x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{equation}
satisfy
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} |k||x_k|^2 <\infty.
\end{equation}

If anyone knows a reference with this definition it would be perfect.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The corresponding definition with $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the domain is given in section 3.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you!